# No login after updating to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, login, 22.04, freeze

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 happily withing VirtualBox for some time.
I recently updated to 22.04 using the software updater.
After the upgrade, on booting the system would only get as far as showing the standard login screen, but without any users visible. It would then freeze.

I can log in successfully using the recovery mode.  Everything seems to work in that mode except that the display is limited to 1024x768.

I've tried pulling the latest updates within recovery mode, but still get the freeze on booting in "normal" mode.

Any suggestions as to how I should start looking for the problem?

Update 2022-09-23 14:30:
The history.log and term.log files don't seem to show any obvious problems during the update process.

/var/log/syslog shows a number of errors during the boot process, the  first of which is:

> Sep 23 13:56:52 tim-VirtualBox systemd-udevd[354]: sr0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sr0' failed with exit code 1.

Later on a crash file is saved to _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash, which includes:

> JournalErrors:
> Sep 23 13:56:45 tim-VirtualBox kernel: RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!
> Sep 23 13:56:45 tim-VirtualBox kernel: acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.

(then lots more information).

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this and how to fix it very welcome.

[Update 28-Nov-2022] I tried many things, none of which fixed the problem.  Eventually I gave up and re-installed Ubuntu22.04 in a fresh new VirtualBox.  That fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I was running whatever the latest version of Ubuntu20 was (20.04?) when I updated to 22.04.  Everything seems to be working in recovery mode except that I'm limited to a low resolution (1024x768) screen.

Comment: Please [edit your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1431884/edit) rather than using comments. Comments are how we help you to improve your question until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation. @guiverc is pointing out that your information so far is either impossible or inaccurate. Try to avoid being inaccurate -- it makes helping you much harder.

Comment: Suggestion: Start with your logs: Review your /var/log/apt logs for errors with your release-upgrade that you did not notice at the time. Also review your /var/log/syslog for errors that occur during boot.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and got this same failure. To fix this I had to up the amount of display memory to 128 MB from 64 MB and changed the Graphics controller to VMSVGA. Not sure which of those actually helped, but I was able to log in after that.

Comment: What is the command to increase the amount of display memory?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply changing the driver to "VMSVGA" was helpful. And this solution will work very easy if you are loading your machine from a VM on a sandbox like VirtualVM or something like this.
Anyway that's for providing this solution.